# Get a List of Custom Field Values limited by post category

Tags: mysql, wordpress, custom-fields

I added a custom field (location) for some posts. I want to get all the locations from posts from a specific post category and store the locations in an array. Then, I want to display them in a dropdown list in the category template file(category-6.php)

I am using wpdb and I am only getting all the locations. I cannot limit them by category.

```
$places = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM 
$wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s ORDER BY meta_value ASC", $metakey) );

if ($places) {
    foreach ($places as $place) {
      echo "<option value=\"" . $place . "\">" . $place . "</option>";
    }
}
```

I need to be able to get all the locations from a specific category id (for example 6). Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this

```
$places = get_posts(array(      
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post__in' => array(6),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'location',            
        )
    )
));

if ($places) {
   echo '<select name="tour" id="t1">';
   foreach ($places as $key) {                              
      echo '<option value="'.$key->slug.'">'.$key->name.'</option>';
   }
   echo '</select>';
}
```

Comment: It is still not working.. 'terms' => 'location' is the custom field value or the category name?

Comment: I do change it, please check and update me if any query.

Comment: still nothing.. i only managed to get the values with wpdb. with get_posts i do not even get the values

Answer (score 0):

You need to query posts from your category first, then iterate over each one to get the meta value for each post.  Try this.

```
$args = array (

  'category' => 6,  /* insert ID of your category */
  'numberposts' => -1 /* -1 for all posts */
);

$posts = get_posts($args); /* get all the posts in the category */

$locations = []; /* set up the array */

foreach ($posts as $post) {

   /* get the location value for each post in the category */

   $meta_location = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'location', false); 

   /* add the value to the array */

   $locations[] = $meta_location;

}

foreach ($locations as $location) {
      echo "<option value=\"" . $location . "\">" . $location . "</option>";
    }
```

Comment: This returns an array. $location returns an array not a string value.